# Masking Labeles in the Compositor in QGIS 2.8.1

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer, expression

[image: picture of situation described in Question]

I am looking for a way to remove/mask out Labels that are under a composer Element (Overview Map), which I moved in front of my main map. 
Is there no way to do this? Maybe using the ItemID?
I tried the mask add-on, but it only seems to work with Polygons, which does not help me here, because the maps are generated by the Atlas function.